# Linear Map and Scalars Question

Tags: linear-algebra

I am having trouble figuring out how to solve the following problem:

Suppose $T\in \mathcal L(\mathbb F^n,\mathbb F^m).$ Show that there exist scalars $A_j,_k \in \mathbb F$ for $j = 1,...,m$ and $k = 1,...,n$ such that:

$T(x_1,...,x_n) = (A_1,_1x_1 +...+ A_1,_nx_n,...,A_m,_1x_1 +...+ A_m,_nx_n)$

for every $(x_1,...,x_n) \in \mathbb F^n$.

How in the world would I solve this problem? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

For $J=1,2,...,n$ let us denote $e_j:=(0,...,0,1,0,...,0) \in \mathbb F^n$

($1$ in the $j$-th place).

Then $T(e_j) \in \mathbb F^m$. Hence there are $A_{j1},...,A_{jm} \in \mathbb F$ such that

$T(e_j)=(A_{j1},...,A_{jm} )$